# Powers of a quotient ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I was studying commutative algebra and I have found several problems and results involving powers of ideals. However, I am not very good at working with those objects and I have found some dificulties.

If $R$ is a ring and $I$ is an ideal of $R$ we can consider the quotient $R\left/I\right.$. Now let $J$ be an ideal of $R$ such that $I\subset J$, then $J\left/I\right.$ is an ideal of $R\left/I\right.$. What can we say abut $\left(J\left/I\right.\right)^n$? Is it true that $\left(J\left/I\right.\right)^n=J^n\left/I\right.$? If not, can we add some conditions on $J$ or $I$ such that this holds? (prime, maximal, principal,...)

So any help will be mostly appreciated, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessarily true, simply because we do not always have $I\subset J^n$. What can be said is that
$$\bigl(J/I\bigr)^n=\bigl(J^n+I\bigr)/I\simeq J^n/\bigl(J^n\cap I\bigr).$$

Comment: so, in general we have $\bigl(J/I\bigr)^n=\bigl(J^n+I\bigr)/I$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It's not hard to see, using the definition of the product of two ideals, and  a nursery school induction.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that is what i need.

Comment: You can note that, more generally, if $J$ is any ideal in $R$, its image in the quotient $R/I$ is $(J+I)/I$.